# STL: соединить два вектора

Tags: c++, массивы, stl, вектор

подскажите, возможно ли вообще решить такую задачу:

есть два вектора пар

```
using pairs_t = std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2>>;

pairs_t data1, data2;
```

требуется пройти по всем элементам этих двух векторов

решением является собрать новый вектор из двух:

```
pairs_t data_total;
data_total.insert(std::end(data_total), std::begin(data1), std::end(data1));
data_total.insert(std::end(data_total), std::begin(data2), std::end(data2));
```

**Вопрос:**
а можно ли не собирать для этой цели отдельный вектор, чтобы избежать ненужных копирований, удалений и т.д.?

и конечно не подходит вариант отдельного обхода векторов

```
for (const auto& obj : data1) {...} 
for (const auto& obj : data2) {...}
```

нужно именно обойти оба вектора так так сказать как единого целого

P.S.

наверное подойдет и промежуточный вариант - собрать новый вектор, но не элементов, а ссылок на элементы, т.е. никаких лишних операций с типами Т1, Т2 происходить не будет

Comment: Добавить в конец 1 вектора другой вектор? (`data1.insert(data1.end(), data2.begin(), data2.end());`)

Comment: @Павел Ериков, не хотелось бы менять ни один из этих двух векторов, кроме того это опять будут ненужные копирования

Comment: Есть такая легендарная штука, прокси. Его можно создать примерно так: class Proxy2Vecor{ array<std::reference_wrapper<vector<int>>,2> vec; class Iter{size_t vec_id; Proxy2Vecor &proxy;};};

Comment: Наверняка на `std::views::join` можно что-то соорудить.

Comment: @Никита Самоуков, попробовал `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<pair_t>>`, но вываливается ошибка `'std::reference_wrapper<pair_t>::reference_wrapper': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types` при попытке сделать `insert`

Comment: @Zhihar Может потому, что нужен массив из 2 ссылок на вектора, а не вектор ссылок. И делать надо не инсерт, а создавать в списке инициализации?

Comment: Proxy2Vecor(vector<int>& a, vector<int>& b):vec({ a, b }){} например

Comment: @Никита Самоуков, по моему вы усложняете.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan тогда напишите ваш вариант попроще.

Comment: С таким решением нужно хранить просто две ссылки. Контейнер  то зачем понадобился?  Я бы написал решение, но не тут не до конца ясна цель. Потому что если просто итерация от начала до конца, то итератору присвоить begin() другого вектора, если он дошел до end() первого. А если  для любой операции, тогда может быть нужно написать свой итератор, хранящий   ссылку на второй вектор. Как его написать, опять же зависит от задачи(должен ли он работать в общих алгоритмах или нужно что то попроще?... Напишешь(один подсказал HolyBlackCat), а потом окажется, что для задач ТС это не совсем подходит.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, задача следующая - у меня есть два вектора, по элементам которого надо пройти `for i {for j}` (т.е. сложность O(n^2)), чтобы не делать искусственно 4 цикла `for i1 {for j1 for j2}, for i2 {for j1 for j2}`, а обойтись двумя `for i {for j}` я объединяю две вектора в один, причем исключительно для этой операции, дальше мне этот объединенный вектор не будет нужен. Но элементы, содержащиеся в векторах могут  при копировании выполнять кучу разных действий с выделением памяти, записью и т.д., поэтому не хочется выполнять лишние и необязательные операции.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, как вариант - создать вектор итераторов, но тогда внутри циклов будут все эти неудобные `->` и т.п., поэтому подумалось, а можно ли сделать вектор ссылок, который не приводит к копированиям элементов, а внутри алгоритма работы с объединенным вектором эти ссылки "прозрачны", т.е. никакая дополнительная сущность не лезет и не мешает

Comment: а кто говорил про векторе итераторов? У вас в мыслях только и вектор крутится. Во вторых пройтись по элементам двух последовательностей, не изменяет сложность, сложность все еще остается O(N)

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, нет, нужна проверка всех со всеми - это `O(n^2)`, а что еще в мыслях должно крутиться?

Comment: В мыслях должно крутится найти правильный подход.  Во первых, далеко не всегда вектора являются самым подходящим контейнером, во вторых я чувствовал и продолжаю чувствовать, что ваш подход к задаче не верный или я  не так понял что вы хотите, по сему я удаляюсь  вместе со своим ответом. А вы можете написать свой итератор, который хранит две ссылки на эти вектора, а не вектор ссылок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118682/discussion-between-zhihar-and-ar-hovsepyan).

Comment: *"конечно не подходит вариант отдельного обхода векторов"* - и чем он не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Долго мучался, нарисовал итератор. Посмотрите, может понравиться:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Os vecpai.cpp -o vecpai
# include <vector>
# include <iostream>
template <class T1,class  T2>
using pairs_t = std::vector<std::pair<T1, T2>>;

template <class T1,class  T2>
class MergeIterator {
public :
  MergeIterator(pairs_t<T1, T2>&a,pairs_t<T1, T2>&b):da{a},db{b}{
    start();}
  void  start(void){
    it = da.begin();
    if(it == da.end())
      it = db.begin();}
  operator bool(){return  it not_eq db.end();}
  MergeIterator<T1,T2> operator  ++(void){
    ++ it;
    if(it == da.end())
      it = db.begin();
    return *this;}
  std::pair<T1, T2> & operator * (){return * it;}
private:
  pairs_t<T1, T2> & da ;
  pairs_t<T1, T2> & db ;
  typename pairs_t<T1, T2>::iterator it ;
};

int main(){
  pairs_t<int, char> data1{{1,'a'},{2,'b'}}, data2{{3,'c'},{4,'d'}};
  for (MergeIterator<int , char> i{data1,data2};i;++i)
    std::cout<<"("<<(*i).first<<","<<(*i).second<<")"<<std::endl;
  }
```

тест :

```
$ ./vecpai 
(1,a)
(2,b)
(3,c)
(4,d)
```